# How do I use nltk.containers.Trie?

Tags: python, data-structures, nltk, trie

I want to use nltk.containers.Trie to perform simple operations like inserting a word into the trie, retrieving all words with a given prefix, find nodes with most descendants (i.e. most common prefixes),  graphically viewing the trie and so on. I couldn't find any documentation whatsoever regarding the use of this structure. Here's all I have so far:

```
from nltk.containers import Trie
t = Trie()
```

I now have a list of words which I need to add to the trie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty cryptic, isn't it. It's basically a dictionary but you can additionally check if a string is a *prefix* of a known key:

```
>>> t = Trie()
>>> t['they'] = 15
>>> 'the' in t
True
>>> print t['the']
None
```

There's also `find_prefix`, which will match as much of its argument as possible, and return the value it finds there (if any) plus the remainder of the argument:

```
>>> t.find_prefix("theirs")
(None, 'irs')                 # Prefix "the" has no value
```

You could take a look at the source in `nltk/containers.py`. The magic is in the methods `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, which handle expressions of the form `t[key]`.

Also good to know: The `keys()` method will only return real entries, not prefixes. You can use it with the method `subtrie` to retrieve all words that begin with a given prefix:

```
>>> t.subtrie('th').keys()
['ey']
```

PS. Note that `containers.py` was removed from the NLTK about six months ago! Before you update your nltk distribution (which you should), save `nltk/containers.py` under a different name. Better yet, just save the `Trie` class. (The rest of the file is obsolete).

Comment: Thanks, that was a lifesaver! However, is there any way find all words starting with a particular prefix, or the number of words with a prefix, or the 'height' of a node, and other such basic tree operations / manipulations?

Comment: Take a look at the source in `nltk/containers.py`, it's pretty straightforward. A Trie is a dictionary plus what you'll find defined there.

Comment: Added info on getting words that start with a prefix; but I've no idea what you mean by the "height" of a node.

Comment: My language is not English. When I try to do (for example): t.subtrie('ওে').keys() (which should return a lot of things), I get the error: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/containers.py", line 163, in subtrie
    curr_node = curr_node[1][char]
KeyError: '\xe0'. What could be the problem?

Comment: No idea, but it's probably caused by the fact that python does not know what language you're using. Use unicode strings and hope that `Trie` supports them. If it does not, I recommend fixing it to support unicode-- it's a very simple module, and you need to understand how python 2 handles unicode anyway.

Comment: If you can't sort it out, compose a new question and give a helpful description of the problem.